# Powershell: Compare-Object Issue

Tags: arrays, powershell, compareobject

I try to compare two Arrays of user accounts and I'd like to find the unique accounts.

Array number one contains following data:

```
PS C:\Users\admin...\Desktop> $ExcludedUsers

Name                                                                               RecipientType                                                                   
----                                                                               -------------  
Desiree AebyADC-695636344                                                          User
```

Array number two contains following data:

```
PS C:\Users\admin...\Desktop> $AllUsers
Name                                                                               RecipientType 
----                                                                               ------------- 
Dejan Schwitter                                                                    User    
Aristoteles Filipe                                                                 User   
Desiree AebyADC-695636344                                                          User
```

The magic should be done by following command:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ExcludedUsers -DifferenceObject $AllUsers -IncludeEqual
```

The result is confusing...

```
InputObject                                                                        SideIndicator  
-----------                                                                        -------------  
cl03.../.../Lernende/_ToBeDeleted/Desiree AebyADC-695636344          ==      
cl03.../.../Lernende/KBA2a/Aristoteles Filipe                        =>    
cl03.../.../Lernende/_ToBeDeleted/Desiree AebyADC-695636344          =>
```

If I do the same with following arrays, I get the right result (4,5)...

```
PS C:\Users\admin...\Desktop> $a1 = @(1,2,3) 
PS C:\Users\admin...\Desktop> $a2 = @(1,2,4,3,5)
```

Where is the mistake? Any Idea?

Comment: `Compare-Object -Property Name, RecipientType`

Comment: Thanks, that's it...  In this case, PS doesn't compare the whole object, right? Which property does PS compare, if I don't specify any?